# Top header to edit page not present in one page

Tags: theme-customizer, headers, dashboard

On one of our wordpress pages (we use polylang and it is only present on one language only), the top bar that appears when logged in as an admin to edit the page, customize the theme, access the dashboard, etc, does not display. It is the only page on our website where this occurs and does not seem to be causing any front end issues, however I am guessing this indicates a technical issue with the code.

What could this be due to? we are trying to solve it and avoid any unnoticed errors but not sure where to start.

When previewing the said page, the bar is present, it is only not present when accessing the published page directly through its URL.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: post some code so we can see and help you with it

Comment: Sounds likely to be a JavaScript problem. Have you tried opening the console to see if there are any JS errors when the page loads?